# Efficiently reformat data layout

Tags: vba, excel, unpivot, sas-macro

I have several Excel spreadsheets with data layout like this [raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOju9.jpg):

[image]

```
company company1    company2    company3
currency     $        Y          E
1/1/2013    32.68   12          3
1/2/2013    12.5    13          4
1/3/2013    45      45          8
```

which basically are time series data grouped together. I need the final layout transformed into panel data, like this [wanted panel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7O7V.jpg):

[image]

Since my observations are usually very large, it is not practical manually to reformat it.

Is there a macro code that can achieve such a goal?

Comment: If it's possible to do it in SAS macro language

Comment: Instead of screenshots, can you copy/paste the data in there? That way we can use it on our end to try it out.

Comment: Thanks. I copy paste it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn on Record Macro if desired. In Excel, move the currency row out of the way. 'Reverse pivot' (as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20543651/1505120)), sort the Table on Column A to Z, switch the order of Columns B and C and fill Column D with a lookup of the company name against your currency indicators.

Comment: As the currency is later needed for the `HLOOKUP`, instead of "moving it out of the way" it can be "filtered out" in the Pivot Table

Comment: Thanks to you, for the wizard and the reverse PivotTable concept. Learned something new today, great...

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions!